# React Dropzone + Redux form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm adding a file input to a Redux form with React Dropzone. Validation function is called and the correct error is returned, but I the values for `error` and `tocuhed` do not change:

The field render method:

```
export const renderDropzoneField = function({ input, name, id, meta: { touched, error } }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropzone
        name={name}
        onDrop={filesToUpload => input.onChange(filesToUpload)}
      >
        Import image to upload
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </Dropzone>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The validate method:

```
export const validateImage = imageList => {
  if (imageList) {
    if (imageList.length > 1) {
      return "You can upload one image at a time";
    } else if (imageList.length === 1) {
      let selectedImage = imageList[0];
      if (!selectedImage.type.match('image.*')) {
        return "Only image files are allowed";
      } else if (selectedImage.size > 1048576) {
        return "Maximum file size exceeded";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The render method:

```
render() {
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this._onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field name="title" label="Name" type="text" component={renderInputField}/>
        <Field name="description" label="Description" type="text" component={renderTextAreaField}/>
        <Field name="amount" label="Amount" type="text" component={renderInputField}/>
        <Field name="image" component={renderDropzoneField}/>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.onClose}>Cancel</button>
      </form>
      { this.state.error ? <span>{this.state.error}</span> : <noscript/> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I load a 'pdf' file (which results in an error message) the `touched` value is still false, and the `error` is `undefiend`.

**Update 1**

The validation is done on the form-level:

```
const validators = [
  {
    field: 'title',
    validator: validateName
  },
  {
    field: 'description',
    validator: validateDescription
  },
  {
    field: 'amount',
    validator: validateAmount
  },
  {
    field: 'image',
    validator: validateImage
  }
];

class NewExpense extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
  }

  _onSubmit = values => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = e => {
      var imageValue = reader.result;
      this.props.createExpense(values, imageValue, this.props.groupId, () => this.props.onClose(), error => this.setState({error: error}));
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(values.image[0]);
  }

  _onImagePreviewChange = files => {
    debugger;
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this._onSubmit.bind(this)) }>
          <Field name="title" label="Name" type="text" component={ renderInputField }/>
          <Field name="description" label="Description" type="text" component={ renderTextAreaField }/>
          <Field name="amount" label="Amount" type="text" component={ renderInputField }/>
          <Field onChange={this._onImagePreviewChange.bind(this)} name="image" label="Image" component={ renderDropzoneField } />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.onClose}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
        { this.state.error ? <span>{this.state.error}</span> : <noscript/> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { createExpense })(reduxForm({
  validate,
  form:'NewExpense',
  validators
})(NewExpense));
```

Comment: What about using `meta.dirty` instead of `touched`? By default `meta.touched` will be set when the field is blurred; in your case you are not blurring the dropzone, just changing its value so `meta.dirty` should be the prop you need.

Comment: what about `error`?

Comment: See if this example helps? https://github.com/BBB/dropzone-redux-form-example/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: I tried that before, it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your code how you trigger the validation (is it submit or field level?). Anyway I assembled a sandbox which works [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ppv14lr5v).
What I did is adding validation property to your field

```
<Field validate={validateImage} name="image" component={renderDropzoneField} />
```

and using `dirty` instead of `touch`

```
{dirty &&(error && <span>{error}</span>)}
```

Comment: I'm doing on form-level. Your example has the same problem as I'm experiencing. Try to upload a video file (an invalid file format) and still you see a value for the preview. How can you limit the preview to be shown only for valid inputs?

Comment: Does this mean that you want to reset the value in case of invalid input?   If so, why do you need this? I'm asking because the form could not be submitted if it doesn't pass the validation, so you might not need to reset the invalid value. I think it would be useful if you post some more line of your code, for instance how the validation is done.

Comment: Ah, I have one more question. This is working fine, but this is missing something, the photo preview display.

Comment: I updated my sandbox with the preview display, you can check it out

Comment: There is still an issue. Even if the validation doesn't pass, we are still going to get it in the `onChange` handler you added to the `Field`.

Comment: any idea on how to stop getting preview if the validation fails?

Comment: you could use action selectors such as `getFormSyncErrors` which will tell you which are the fields with errors in your form. Then in case of error on a specific field, you can reset its value to its default with `this.props.change(fieldName, fieldDefaultValue);`

Comment: I tried what you said, but I see another problem: `onChange` handler function `_onImagePreviewChange` executes after validation functions, therefore the field-level error value returned by `getFormSyncErrors` is stale:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936192/redux-form-validation-runs-before-onchange-handler-function

Comment: I meant to say "onChange handler function _onImagePreviewChange executes BEFORE validation functions"

Comment: Yes that is normal behavior, you need to change something to trigger the validation and within `onChange` you still can't see how the next validation status is gonna be. try to use `componentWillReceiveProps`,  check this updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/40zj98wnlw

Answer (score 0):

Are you preventing the default action from occuring when you submit your form?  If not the page is going to refresh and wipe out the touched and error states.

In `handleSubmit(event)` you should include the line:

`event.preventDefault();`

This will prevent the page from refreshing when clicking Submit.

Comment: This happens even before submitting. I expect the validation result (possible error message) to update `touched` and `error`, which doesn't happen. (this is true for other simple html input types such as `textarea`, or `input`)